# Which IPC has the simplest implementation in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, client-server, ipc

I have a multiple server client application in C# . My requirement is to exchange some float values between different clients.Which IPC mechanism is best & easy to use. I read shared memory is simplest but then it uses pointers which is considered as unsafe code in C#.
Can you suggest me other mechanisms? Code examples will be very welcome .

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using WCF named pipes. Here are some major procedures.

1. Define two interfaces, say, IServerActions and IClientActions
   IServerActions defines methods to be invoked by client applications; IClientActions defines methods for server to invoke individually or broadcast.
   IServerActions should include a Register method.
2. Implement the two interfaces in client and server applications.
   The implementation classes could be the main form or any singleton class within the app.
3. Client to server and server to client communications are similar, creating a named pipe channel and invoking methods.
   Client gets a unique ID (eg. Guid.NewGuid()) and registers on the server.
   Server maintains a list of client IDs and can create separate channels for broadcasting a message (sending the floating number in your case)

Here's a good example solution in .NET C#.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7176/Inter-Process-Communication-in-NET-Using-Named-Pip